# Strong typed stringified object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define a strongly typed stringified object.

rather than having `type SomeType = string`, I'd like to have a more descriptive type something like

```
type SomeType = Stringified<{
           prop1: 'value1', 
           prop2: 'value2'
         }>
```

At the end of the day, the value of `type SomeType` is a `string`, but that `string` has a particular structure.

Even if TypeScript cannot validate this type and will accept any `string`, I'd still like to use it as it makes for more readable code.

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Specific structure is structure like? Please describe and give specific examples

Comment: Are you looking for a [nominal type alias](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)?  You could emulate that with something like the code shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXOgDW), although there are caveats.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Its possible with https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html. If you describe the proposed string structure it would help.

Comment: @adsy I don't see how template literal types will help unless you write a generic checker and it would require the stringified string types to be known at compile time, which seems unlikely.  Could you demonstrate how it would work?

Comment: You would only need to know the *structure* ahead of time and not the full possible set of strings. I think that satisfies your requirement? Will be easier to answer if you give an example structure.

Comment: I think @jcalz's suggestion is probably the closest to what I'm after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you won't actually know the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the stringified values at *compile time*; that is, you are *not* going to deal with TypeScript code of the form

```
// you're not going to really have code like this
const stringifiedThing: SomeType = "{\"prop1\": \"value1\", \"prop2\": \"value2\"}";
```

where you want the compiler to actually *validate* whether the string literal above conforms to your type.

If I'm wrong about that assumption, then you could *try* to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to parse the string literal and check it.  But implementing parsers with template literal types is tricky and complicated.  There's not even an accurate specific type you could use for `SomeType` above.  The following is the closest you can get, using *pattern template literal types* as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598):

```
type SomeType = `{"prop1": "${string}", "prop2": "${string}"}`;
```

But that's not accurate, since `` `${string}` `` matches any string whatsoever, even ones containing quotation marks and backslashes, and so the following is accepted when it shouldn't be:

```
const badlyStringifiedThing: SomeType = 
  "{\"prop1\": \"value1\\\", \"prop2\": \"value2\"}";

console.log(JSON.parse(badlyStringifiedThing)); // RUNTIME ERROR!
```

Maybe that inaccuracy would be acceptable, but you'd still find yourself hard-pressed to write a `Stringified<T>` type that produced reasonable template literal types for all `T` inputs.

And again, all that complexity would only help you in the unlikely situation that the stringified values are hardcoded in TypeScript code somewhere.  If these stringified values are, instead, the result of runtime stringifications only, then even a perfect compile-time string parser would be of little use.

---

All right, so if you don't need to validate these strings at compile time, then really what you want is for `Stringified<T>` to be a [*nominal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) subtype of `string` which depends on `T`.  So even though it's just a `string` type, the compiler wouldn't let you assign random `string`s to it.

Well, TypeScript doesn't really have direct nominal types, but you can simulate them with [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), as described in the TypeScript FAQ entry [Can I make a type alias nominal?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).  You do it by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `string` with an object type containing a "phantom" property whose type depends on `T`.  Here's one way:

```
type Stringified<T> = string & { __structure: T }
```

So the compiler views a `Stringified<T>` as a `string` which has a `__structure` property of type `T`.  At runtime this will not be true, so that's why `__structure` is a phantom property.  It only exists in the TypeScript type system and not at runtime.

This means you'll need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) when you want to assign a `string` to these types, since the compiler knows that `string`s don't have that `__structure` property.  So you could provide a `stringify()` helper function that does this to discourage others from doing so haphazardly:

```
function stringify<T>(t: T): Stringified<T> {
    return JSON.stringify(t) as Stringified<T>; // need assertion here
}
```

And now that you have this, you could provide the corresponding `parse()` function which converts a `Stringified<T>` into a `T`.  (This also isn't type safe, since the compiler can't possibly know that `JSON.parse(s)` produces a `T`.  Since `JSON.parse()`'s return type is [the unsafe `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), you don't need an explicit type assertion, but that doesn't mean the compiler has validated it... more like the compiler doesn't even try.)

```
function parse<T>(s: Stringified<T>): T {
    return JSON.parse(s); // this type checks but isn't validated
}
```

And so armed with these, you can `parse()` the result of `stringify()` and the compiler will keep track of the stringified type:

```
const foo = stringify({ a: 1, b: "two" });

const val = parse(foo);
console.log(val.b.toUpperCase()); // compiler knows that val has a string
```

And you won't be allowed to `parse()` a random string:

```
parse("oopsie"); // error!  Argument of type 'string' is not 
// assignable to parameter of type 'Stringified<unknown>'.
```

So there you go, this is the closest I can imagine getting to a TypeScript type representing a stringified object.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-TChhmNEMQYQJgN7Kog3gABrYCFlSBgLSgYAlS4s0sHDBUfGjH5qmcDw0DQctQP-SgHRkcRdAWGQBAYAB3NABC7GZd25ZwzSOSjJLQXTKnEgEgRaM06gWOoGDQbEYHIYQUCAwZkT0ydxQhAQpJgKBvAEaihSNURhGpOgAEFhDUVJIGALi0ADRilQrNUsGA4A0C42CsDUUAFjwRhpL6cAIH1f1GE4JVhzhMZCwPFjsvU4ASyVOpYyAA)